# Avoid R output leaking into LaTeX with ggnet

Tags: r, knitr, tex, ggally

Please consider the following MWE which I compile into a .tex document via `knitr`

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE>>=
library(igraph)
library(GGally)
library(network)
library(sna)

# Set up data
set.seed(123)
g <- barabasi.game(1000)

# Plot data
ggnet(g, weight.method = "indegree")

@


\end{document}
```

which inserts

```
\begin{verbatim}
## 1000 nodes, weighted by indegree 
## 
##    id indegree outdegree freeman
## 4   4       47         1      48
## 12 12       37         1      38
## 3   3       34         1      35
## 13 13       32         1      33
## 1   1       23         0      23
## 11 11       19         1      20
\end{verbatim}
```

in my .tex.

How could I control it?

Comment: I don't use/have `ggnet`, so my apologies for a blind attempt: does `invisible(ggnet(...))` work?

Comment: @r2evans. Nope, I also tried `sink()` with no success.

Comment: Just in case, please post `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Put `results='hide'` in your chunk's parameter, it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `results = 'hide'`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

<<echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, results = 'hide'>>=
library(igraph)
library(GGally)
library(network)
library(sna)

# Set up data
set.seed(123)
g <- barabasi.game(1000)

# Plot data
ggnet(g, weight.method = "indegree")

@


\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to actually put it ^^